# Python with Seleneium Webdriver, reading a button and saving its text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

so Ive been using selenium webdriver in Python3 right now, so far its working great and I can do most the things Id like, one thing though, on instagram, the xpath for the follow or following button is the same, Id assume it is for all web pages with buttons in the same place, but if the text and color are different when its follow vs following, is there a way to let python discern that?
Id like to write sort of like an if follow: do this, elif following: do this
the xpath for the button is this:

```
/html/body/span/section/main/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/button
```

in html the text is different and all but I dont know how to make this work, if any of you have any advice thatd be great!

Comment: Any XPath that starts with "/html..." is going to be brittle and unreliable. Learn XPath.

Comment: Provide `html` code sample with attributes and its values for button which text you want to get

Comment: What would I have to learn in Xpath, SiKing? The path works it just doesnt diffrentiate between follow and following

Comment: Okay anderson, heres the two buttons :      <button class="_jvpff _k2yal _988x3 _i46jh _nv5lf" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0:0.1.0.2.0">Following</button>  and      <button class="_jvpff _k2yal _csba8 _i46jh _nv5lf" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0:0.1.0.2.0">Follow</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "find" `Following` button you should use next `xpath`:

```
//button[@class="_jvpff _k2yal _988x3 _i46jh _nv5lf"]'
```

while for the `Follow`:

```
//button[@class="_jvpff _k2yal _csba8 _i46jh _nv5lf"]
```

Text of a button could be defined like this:

```
follow = driver._find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="_jvpff _k2yal _csba8 _i46jh _nv5lf"]').text
```

Comment: Not sure I put in the Xpath right, just used the Xpath I had and the .text worked perfectly,I googled it and couldnt find it anywhere, where is '.text' for selenium documented? So I can find the answer myself next time, feel bad because everyone down voted by question for some reason, thank you for your help!